# How long does loot stay persistent for?

Tags: dayz-standalone

If I pick up some loot then drop it somewhere, how long will it stay there for? Will it be there next server reset?

I know it use to be forever but I think I heard there is a point that it disappears now, or is someone telling me lie?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did a bit of research and read two ideas regarding persistent loot.
1. Loot left on the ground despawns on server reset.
2. Every item has a lifetime value for how long it can stay on the ground before despawning.

> Each item in persistence binary also carries a lifetime value, Aka the time in seconds it can stay on the ground before expiring. Tents and backpacks/cases have the value greatly increased while other items diminish in matter of hours. Thus the loot caches should only happen with tents/cases/backpacks. While the system cleanes these items, it quickly starts restocking the original spawn points (memory points on buildings). Items in tents/backpacks/player inventories are not part of the calculation

More information about spawning of items:

> Each server oscillates between 19k-25k items with total maximum set to 45k. Respawn tick happens every 5 seconds as does cleanup. Each class has nominal/minimal/maximum values defined. When a items class gets to a minimal value (usualy about 50%) it start respawning based on priorities.

[Source](http://www.dayztv.com/standalone/dayz-persistent-storage-tents/)

Comment: I believe this extends for other items as well, like vehicles.